# chrome extension: send data to not permitted URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible for a chrome extension to send data to a not permitted URL (URL not listed in the permissions in MANIFEST.json) ?

Comment: Not directly. It can use a malicious site that's listed in manifest.json and that provides proxy-like API for the extension so it can use the site as a proxy to access other URLs. An extension can use nativeMessaging API and a separate utility that does the proxying.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be by changing the links on the current website:

- copy the `href` attribute of all `a` tags a temporary `targetURL` variable.
- change the `href` attribute of all `a` tags to a `proxyURL` link to a proxy server and attach the desired data as POST data in the `proxyURL`.
- attach the `targetURL` as POST data in the `proxyURL`.
- the proxy server reads the desired data, saves it, and redirects to the `targetURL`.